# Flask application with two modules, both must have separate flask-login

Tags: flask, flask-login

I am creating a Flask election application that has two main modules: a `manage` module, to manage the elections you create, and a `vote` module, where the electorate can vote. `manage` and `vote` are both implemented with Blueprints.

Both sections require authentication, so specific users can't edit each others elections and so voters can be authenticated to only vote once. Due to the intended use case, voters (in `vote` module) are identified by a username alone, and election managers (in `manage`) have a username and password (not sure if this is relevant).

I have implemented the `manage` system fine, but my issue comes with implementing the `vote` module. Since I am using `flask-login` in the `manage` module, whenever an election manager is logged in, it counts as being logged in on the `vote` module too, which causes undefined behavior when navigating between modules. I need the user authentication to be separate in both modules.

How can I create separate `flask-login` instances, both running in the same app, such that `current_user` in the `manage` module is not the same as in `vote` module? I've looked into doing this with cookies, but all the solutions online have revolved around creating separate instances for different apps on the same server, not different modules in the same app.

Comment: Just to be sure, "manager" can vote? I guess somewhere you are using some kind of database? Does your problem exist because your using the same table for both module?

Comment: No, manager wouldn't be able to vote. I am using a MongoDB database on the backend; the documents in the collection are "elections". Inside each election there is a field for the manager/owner's ID and a list of voter IDs for the election. The voter IDs are just randomly generated strings that will be unique to each election. Votes are stored in another collection/table. My issue is that I want managers to be able to stay logged in (to the `manage` side) when using/testing the `vote` side.

Comment: without code it's hard to say but i'd tackle this by using two different forms or an `if` condition if there's a password field. If manager form is used, then don't process the vote count. Or, customize your login process, (`flask-login` seems pretty open for that), with an `if` before your `vote` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem, or at least a workaround:

You can create a `User` base class with a `Manager` and `Voter` classes inheriting from it. For all the `manage` pages, when querying the `current_user` also perform a check to see if it is a `Manager`; otherwise if it is a `Voter`, then force logout and let a manager log in. Do the same for the `vote` module, just check the role and force a logout if appropriate.

The benefits of this is that there is never undefined behaviour; however, it doesn't allow for switching easily between a manager and voter, as when you navigate to the other module you are logged out of the previous one. While this behaviour would be fine in production (since you shouldn't be managing an election and having a person vote on the same computer), it makes it a pain during testing and setup of the election. To get around the forced log out, sign into the manager account/module in one browser and voter accounts/module in a different one so you never get forced logged out.

I am still open to a solution that allows both logins to persist independently of each other.